# How to make a Stopwatch app in reactjs?

Tags: stopwatch

[1]How to make a stopwatch app like this https://www.online-stopwatch.com/countdown/ in reactjs...?

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';

export default class StopWatch extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
      time2: ''
    }
  }
  timeCount(){
    this.time= setInterval(() => {
      this.setState({ time2:this.state.time2 - 1});
    },1000);
  }
  stopTimer() {
    clearInterval(this.time);
  }
  componentDidUpdate(){
    console.log(this.state.time2);
    if(this.state.count===0){
      clearInterval(this.time);
    }
  }
  componentWillUnmount(){
    clearInterval(this.time);
  }

  toggle(key){
    if(this.state.time2.length < 6) {
      this.setState({ time2: `${this.state.time2}` + `${key}` });
    }
  }
```

[2]:Value of timer is not changing after trigger buttons.Provide me the 
     best method to achieve this.

Reference Link: https://www.online-stopwatch.com/countdown/